# Redirecting duplicate values to a new file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have a abc.log file that contains filenames like so

```
  cat abc.log
  >
  a.arc
  a.arc 
  b.arc
  c.arc
  c.arc
  d.arc
  e.arc
  e.arc
  f.arc
```

i need a shell script that scans the abc.log file and redirect only the duplicate values to def.log

requirement:

```
        cat def.log
        >
        a.arc
        c.arc
        e.arc                       
               /*only the duplicate values in abc.log*/
```

edit:

```
   cat abc.log        /*may be unsorted too */
      >
       a.arc
       b.arc 
       c.arc
       a.arc
       c.arc
       e.arc
       e.arc
       d.arc
```

any suggestions

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@timrau's answer is better than this:

```
awk '++seen[$0] == 2' in > out
```

The only advantage here is the input does not need to be sorted.

Comment: thanks was looking for solution for unsorted contents in abc.log

Comment: what if the repeated count is 2 or 3 how shud i modify the awk

Comment: @user3186568 Even if there are more duplication, this awk command only prints the line when it reaches the duplicated line for the 2nd time. Thus, it still works for duplication more than 2.

Comment: from the sample only, $1 should be better, which will avoid white  space issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `uniq -d`.

```
uniq -d abc.log > def.log
```

Note that in your question there is a trailing space in the 2nd line but not in the 1st line, which makes `uniq` treating them as different.

For unsorted input:

```
sort abc.log | uniq -d > def.log
```

Comment: can u provide solution for a unsorted scenario

Comment: @NaveenReddy Edited for unsorted input